# Plumbing - what is this bag for? Moisture collection?

Tags: plumbing

I bought a rehab house and looking at the plumbing.
Some weird bag was hanging off one of the pipes.
When I touched it - these pink beads spilled.
Does it have any purpose?

[image]

Comment: bag of wet desiccant? Pipe would just be a thing to hang it off. Judging by the mold, it was being asked to do a bit more than could be expected.

Comment: @Ecnerwal ahh. so desiccant is usually transparent and changes color once it get's wet? make sense. Mold id there because pipes burst this winter. it's a rehab house I bought.:)

Comment: I would agree with @Ecnerwal. It probably isn't so smart to hang it from a pipe since the moisture from the bag could corrode the pipe and fill the basement with water. If that happened, it would be kind of ironic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bag and its content aren't related with plumbing at all. Purpose of this bag is (or was) to collect moisture. You should throw it away ASAP, because it might be toxic....after that try to find out what is causing moisture and fix the problem.

Comment: how much should I pay a plumber to walk me through a house and explain where everything is and what is everything for? (im a total newb in homeownership)

Comment: @Dannyboy that's really hard to tell...varies from country to country, from plumber to plumber....but I guess that it should be max one daily wage. But for this purpose, it would be far better if you could find a friend or someone close to you to walk you through. One of the reasons is that if plumber realizes that you have no clue he might over charge you any repair....Plus, it’s not that hard and you can always ask here. I'll be glad to help if I can.

Comment: @Dannyboy -- If you're going to hire someone, don't hire a plumber.  Instead, hire a home inspector.  A good inspector knows about every system in the house and will be very willing to explain everything.  Usually, you hire an inspector before you buy the house to make sure there isn't anything wrong with it.  If you did this and weren't around on the day of his inspection, then call him back and offer to hire him to redo the inspection, minus the write-up, in order to get the guided tour.

Comment: @BillNace that was a REO foreclosed house purchase - all cash. Frozen pipes and flooded basement. Very cheap for the area. No inspections kinda deal. there were 20 offers on it - but I won. lol. but yeah - thanks for the advice - Ill hire an inspector then.